# how to get value of cos90 in double operand in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, floating-point

I am trying to run my program and i am using

```
double result = cos(90*M_PI/180);
NSLog("Cos 90 value %g",result);  //Prints 6.12323e-17
```

But when i run this

```
 NSLog("Cos 90 value %f",cos(90*M_PI/180)); //Prints 0
```

I want to get value of cos90 in result(double) which should be 0.I know thats floating point airthmetic issue.But how to solve it.Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the thing you want solved?

Comment: `M_PI_2` (another way to express `90*M_PI/180`) is slightly less than the "actual" `PI/2` so the cosine is slightly more than zero - by 6E-17. Using `float` masks the issue because it has less precision.

Comment: Yes i want to know how can i get value of cos90 to be 0?Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if i use M_PI_2 instead of M_PI will i get same value for other calculations like cos30 and other trigonometric values?

Comment: @SahilWasan If you use `cos(M_PI_2/3)` you'll get the same value as `cos(30*M_PI/180)`, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lastly I found solution.All the explanation are right but "temporary" solution to this problem is with `NSNumberFormatter.`

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:NO];
[formatter setAllowsFloats:YES];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:10]; //THIS IS IMPORTANT AS AFTER DECIMAL, DIGITS SHOULD BE LESS THAN 17 because there is difference of 6.12323e-17 

double result = cos(90*M_PI/180);
NSNumber *numberResult = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:result];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:number]); //Prints 0
```

It's a temporary solution.You can also prints value of cos 90 with %f but it will also prints unwanted six 0 after decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Since the argument of `cos` is in radians, to calculate the cosine of 90º, you would pass π/2 radians. π/2 is approximately 1.570796326794896619. The IEEE 754 double closest to π/2 is approximately 1.570796326794896558. Obviously, these are different. The cosine of the latter is approximately 6.123•10<sup>-17</sup>. So, your cosine routine is working correctly; it is returning the cosine of the number it is passed.

It is impossible to pass π/2 to `cos`, because π/2 is not representable as a double.

Depending on your requirements, there may be workarounds. For example, this expression will return (approximately) the cosine of x (in degrees), and will be exactly zero when x is 90: `sin(M_PI/180*(90-x))`.

Comment: Does Objective C provide the functions sinpi() and cospi()? When using cospi() instead of cos() Sahil would get the desired result, since cospi(0.5) is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the result it too small. The only difference is the format specifier. `%g` and `%f` are different; `%f` has six points of precision after the decimal normally while `%g` represents small numbers using scientific notation. You can extend the amount of characters printed after the decimal using `%.100f`, where `100` is the number of characters after the decimal. That's not very precise, though, and precision is not guaranteed after so many decimal places

EDIT: Well, now I noticed what you were actually trying to calculate. It's not zero because floating-point arithmetic at that level is imprecise, due to rounding and such.